# Unmount a desktop

Tags: unmount

I was attempting to mount a iso file to a file on my desktop but unintentionally I mounted my desktop by mistake. Now my desktop is readonly and I can not fix it. I tried searching but I was unable to solve it. If one could spare some help thank you :)

I am new to ubuntu so sorry for my lack of knowledge.

*Edit*
I used the desktop as a mount point using gmount-iso. Now its readonly.

Comment: Can you please add the output of the `ls -ld ~/Desktop` command to your post (plus the actual command that got you in trouble, if you remember it) - I'm not sure it's possible to mount your actual desktop, since it's not a block device - maybe you just changed its permissions or ownership?

Comment: To run that command, press Ctrl+Alt+T for a terminal. Please also run `mount`. Can you tell us more about what you did? What do you mean when you say you "mounted [your] desktop"? Did you mount something with your desktop as the mount point? It's okay if you're not familiar with technical terminology, or cannot answer this specifically. You can just *edit your question* and add as much more description to it as possible about what you did and what happened. It would probably be hard for anyone to answer this right now, but with more information it should be possible to figure this out. Thanks!

Comment: I used my desktop as the mount point. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The command to unmount is called `umount` (note the lack of an 'n'). You can specify what you want to unmount using either the mountpoint or the block device that you mounted there - in this case using the mountpoint will be easier

```
umount ~/Desktop
```

If you used `sudo` to mount, you will need to do the same to `umount`. The original Desktop files should still be there 'underneath' the mount, and should reappear automatically.

Alternatively, unless you made the mount persistent by editing your `/etc/fstab` file, you could simply reboot.